# Identify key uniquely from WM_KEYDOWN message

Tags: winapi, keyboard, keypress, scancodes

I tried to use the virtual key code provided by wParam, however that didn't work very well:

- multiple keys mapped to the same key code
- some keys were not recognized at all
- virtual keys seemed to be adapted to the keyboard layout (which i don't want/need)

Then i saw that the lParam will give me a scancode along with an "extended" flag, which seem to produce a different value for every single key on the keyboard when calculated like this:

```
value = (lParam & 0x01FF0000) >> 16;
```

Will this value always be identical for the same key on the keyboard, even across various keyboards/systems?

Answer (score 1):

Scancodes can be different for different keyboards. Best to use virtual key codes. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646267(v=vs.85).aspx:

> Assigned to each key on a keyboard is a unique value called a scan
>   code, a device-dependent identifier for the key on the keyboard. A
>   keyboard generates two scan codes when the user types a key—one when
>   the user presses the key and another when the user releases the key.
>
> The keyboard device driver interprets a scan code and translates
>   (maps) it to a virtual-key code, a device-independent value defined by
>   the system that identifies the purpose of a key.